# What are some alternatives to git rev-list as this is sometimes slow?

Tags: performance, git, version-control

I've got a tool in production which calls git rev-list on a single, large repo 10-30 times per minute. I'm seeing git response times vary widely, from around 1 second to as much as 50 seconds (before timeout mechanism abandons the git request).

```
git rev-list --pretty=raw 2ef9fa0d0fa4c34d57103a0545b3cc96c2552e6f..f5daa48ebcd3cc95a0df683f8c3a3ad64def4a6e
```

The goal is to see if the two commits are ancestors/descendants and if so, which of the two is the ancestor. I make this call once, if I get output I have my answer, if no output, I swap the commit positions and run again. If no output this time then they are not ancestors/descendants of one another.

Is there another, more efficient way, to find this information? If it comes to it, even suggestions on modeling the commit tree in some structure outside of git are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: With Git 2.20+ (Q4 2018), this will be faster: see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52505170/6309).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `git merge-base first-sha1 second-sha1`. If the result is a third sha1, they are not descendents. Otherwise, the result is the older ancestor.

However, if you could describe at a higher level some of the work flow, there's probably an easier way and you may not have to rely on this. I wrote this article about Branch per Feature: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/ It may give you some ideas.

Comment: The work flow is that we run tests on git committed CAD collateral. Various engineers have local repos, for which we track the test runs. I use this commit ancestor mechanism to tell which test result has the most relevance (the test result which was run on the most recent CAD collateral). When two commits are not ancestors of each other, the failing test is reported to be pessimistic.

Comment: 'git merge-base' looks promising. For my purpose, is simply running 'git merge-base' sufficient? If the result is one of the sha1 arguments then the other sha1 can be considered more recent. If its neither, then they are not ancestors of each other. Is this correct?

Comment: Using just merge-base instead of rev-list seems to work and is on average about twice as fast. I guess this makes sense since you only need one call to merge-base and you can at times need two calls to rev-list. Thanks!

Comment: Corrected my answer. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

[git merge-base](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) (and even [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)) will be even faster with:

- [commit graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49826884/6309) ([mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52246272/6309))
- Git 2.20 (Q4 2018)

That is because both are base on the concept of "commits being reachable".

And recent update broke the reachability algorithm when refs (e.g. tags) that point at objects that are not commit were involved, which has been fixed.

See [commit 4067a64](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4067a64672f9db8ca38d5a2682a7cdba7938c18b), [commit b67f6b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b67f6b26e354813d8cd792dcb3eb1a1b60b98a08) (21 Sep 2018), [commit 6621c83](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6621c838743812aaba96e55cfec8524ea1144c2d) (28 Aug 2018), and [commit 6cc01743](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6cc017431c1c48f80d1c6512fdcc9866cf4b7f55) (20 Jul 2018) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0f7ac90](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f7ac90dbe7ecf511883b7aae84acbb698418f60), 24 Sep 2018)</sup>

> ### `commit-reach`: use `can_all_from_reach`

> The `is_descendant_of` method previously used **`in_merge_bases()`** to check if the commit can reach any of the commits in the provided list.
> This had two performance problems:
>
> 1. The performance is quadratic in worst-case.
> 2. A single `in_merge_bases()` call requires walking beyond the target    commit in order to find the full set of boundary commits that may be merge-bases.
>
> The `can_all_from_reach` method avoids this quadratic behavior and can limit the search beyond the target commits using generation numbers.
> It requires a small prototype adjustment to stop using `commit-date` as a cutoff, as that optimization is no longer appropriate here.
>
> Since `in_merge_bases()` uses `paint_down_to_common()`, `is_descendant_of()` naturally found cutoffs to avoid walking the entire commit graph.
> Since we want to always return the correct result, we cannot use the `min_commit_date` cutoff in `can_all_from_reach`. We then rely on generation numbers to provide the cutoff.
>
> Since not all repos will have a commit-graph file, nor will we always have generation numbers computed for a commit-graph file, create a new method, `generation_numbers_enabled()`, that checks for a commit-graph file and sees if the first commit in the file has a non-zero generation number.
> In the case that we do not have generation numbers, use the old logic for `is_descendant_of()`.
>
> Performance was measured on a copy of the Linux repository using the '`test-tool reach is_descendant_of`' command using this input:
>
> ```
> A:v4.9
> ```
>
> X:v4.10
> X:v4.11
> X:v4.12
> X:v4.13
> X:v4.14
> X:v4.15
> X:v4.16
> X:v4.17
> X.v3.0
>
> Note that this input is tailored to demonstrate the quadratic nature of the previous method, as it will compute merge-bases for v4.9 versus all of the later versions before checking against v4.1.
>
> ```
> Before: 0.26 s
> After: 0.21 s
> ```
>
> Since we previously used the is_descendant_of method in the `ref_newer` method, we also measured performance there using '`test-tool reach ref_newer`' with this input:
>
> ```
> A:v4.9
> B:v3.19
>
> Before: 0.10 s
> After: 0.08 s
> ```
>
> By adding a new commit with parent v3.19, we test the non-reachable case
> of ref_newer:
>
> ```
> Before: 0.09 s
> After: 0.08 s
> ```

---

And before Git 2.20 (Q4 2018), the generation of (experimental) commit-graph files have so far been fairly silent, even though it takes noticeable amount of time in a meaningfully large repository.
**The users will now see progress output.**

See [commit 6b89a34](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b89a34c89fc763292f06012318b852b74825619) (19 Sep 2018), and [commit 1f7f557](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f7f557fd3eca251b1b14fa8240e1a12597c8730), [commit 7b0f229](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b0f2292224cec841de78acc911e4c378ea79faa) (17 Sep 2018) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
Helped-by: Martin Ågren martin.agren@gmail.com.
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 36d767d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/36d767d02e12c1ff991511b7bd8c1d023340f2ca), 16 Oct 2018)</sup>

---

With Git 2.21 (Q1 2019), that progress will be more accurate:

See [commit 01ca387](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01ca387774b6e0f9949f3c1cf6a1ffa3a2409865) (19 Nov 2018) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
Helped-by: [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d4c9027](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4c90270215ba5600ca9cab69185da2027bbf892), 14 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### `commit-graph`: split up `close_reachable()` progress output

> Amend the progress output added in [7b0f229](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b0f2292224cec841de78acc911e4c378ea79faa) ("`commit-graph write`:
> add progress output", 2018-09-17) so that the total numbers it reports
> aren't higher than the total number of commits anymore.
> See [this thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/20181010203738.GE23446@szeder.dev/) for a bug report pointing that out.
>
> When I added this I wasn't intending to provide an accurate count, [but
> just have some progress output to show the user the command wasn't
> hanging](https://public-inbox.org/git/87pnwhea8y.fsf@evledraar.gmail.com/). But since we are showing numbers, let's make them
> accurate. [The progress descriptions were suggested by Derrick Stolee](https://public-inbox.org/git/f7a0cbee-863c-61d3-4959-5cec8b43c705@gmail.com/).
>
> [As noted in the original thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/87pnwhea8y.fsf@evledraar.gmail.com/), we are unlikely to show anything except the "Expanding reachable..." message even on fairly large repositories such as
> `linux.git`.
> On a test repository I have with north of 7 million commits
> all of these are displayed. Two of them don't show up for long, but as
> [noted in  future-proofing](https://public-inbox.org/git/87murle8da.fsf@evledraar.gmail.com/) this fo

---

And (still Git 2.21, Q1 2019), the codepath to show progress meter while writing out commit-graph file has been improved.

See [commit 49bbc57](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49bbc57a5728880bcf2c4a02289508f7d923e32a), [commit 890226c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/890226ccb57d6f9657c29aadfe1c106b939afbc8), [commit e59c615](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e59c615e3c91c481587f9a13d05886082f518cec), [commit 7c7b8a7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c7b8a7fc7c87011d5b3e384122ce8b23ef280e8), [commit d9b1b30](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9b1b309cfc0ebbe5ac689e1131f8c85b025c8c7), [commit 2894473](https://github.com/git/git/commit/289447397c311d7f8b3c7ed2e54e11b6e57a1d89), [commit 53035c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/53035c4f0b06c7e556ab35acb2ce3aff1ba3ff5d) (19 Jan 2019) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
See [commit 857ba92](https://github.com/git/git/commit/857ba928a4125251f2b4a728ff8021d2adcdbd91) (23 Jan 2019), and [commit 5af7417](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5af7417bd869d935715a56b2ccdee04d3a79a328) (19 Jan 2019) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e5eac57](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5eac5735609722a07401a279a1508ace22fc9bc), 05 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### `commit-graph` write: add intermediate progress

> Add progress output to sections of code between "`Annotating[...]`" and
> "`Computing[...]generation numbers`".
> This can collectively take 5-10 seconds on a large enough repository.
>
> On a test repository with I have, with ~7 million commits and ~50 million objects, we'll now emit:
>
> ```
> $ ~/g/git/git --exec-path=$HOME/g/git commit-graph write
> Finding commits for commit graph among packed objects: 100% (124763727/124763727), done.
> Loading known commits in commit graph: 100% (18989461/18989461), done.
> Expanding reachable commits in commit graph: 100% (18989507/18989461), done.
> Clearing commit marks in commit graph: 100% (18989507/18989507), done.
> Counting distinct commits in commit graph: 100% (18989507/18989507), done.
> Finding extra edges in commit graph: 100% (18989507/18989507), done.
> Computing commit graph generation numbers: 100% (7250302/7250302), done.
> Writing out commit graph in 4 passes: 100% (29001208/29001208), done.
> ```
>
> Whereas on a medium-sized repository such as `linux.git`, these new progress bars won't have time to kick in and as before and we'll still emit output like:

> ```
> $ ~/g/git/git --exec-path=$HOME/g/git commit-graph write
> Finding commits for commit graph among packed objects: 100% (6529159/6529159), done.
> Expanding reachable commits in commit graph: 815990, done.
> Computing commit graph generation numbers: 100% (815983/815983), done.
> Writing out commit graph in 4 passes: 100% (3263932/3263932), done.
> ```

---

Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) adds a few fixes to make it faster.

See [commit dd2e50a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd2e50a84ea431a6cec69f37251f29bf3cfcbb68) (07 Sep 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit 67fa6aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/67fa6aac5af508b307c0d6968a28d50d14e7c026) (07 Sep 2019) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cda8faa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cda8faa37e997f5db3458c1454ffe70f5c460d2a), 07 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### `commit-graph`: turn off `save_commit_buffer`

> The commit-graph tool may read a lot of commits, but it only cares about
> parsing their metadata (parents, trees, etc) and doesn't ever show the
> messages to the user.
> And so it should not need `save_commit_buffer`, which is meant for holding onto the object data of parsed commits so that we can show them later. In fact, it's quite harmful to do so.
> According to massif, the max heap of "`git commit-graph write --reachable`" in `linux.git` before/after this patch (removing the commit graph file in between) goes from `~1.1GB` to `~270MB`.
>
> Which isn't surprising, since the difference is about the sum of the
> uncompressed sizes of all commits in the repository, and this was
> equivalent to leaking them.
>
> This obviously helps if you're under memory pressure, but even without
> it, things go faster.
> **My before/after times for that command (without massif) went from `12.521s` to `11.874s`, a speedup of `~5%`**.

And:

> ### `commit-graph`: don't show progress percentages while expanding reachable commits
>
> Commit [49bbc57](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49bbc57a5728880bcf2c4a02289508f7d923e32a) (commit-graph write: emit a percentage for all
> progress, 2019-01-19, Git v2.21.0-rc0) was a bit overeager when it added progress
> percentages to the "Expanding reachable commits in commit graph" phase
> as well, because most of the time the number of commits that phase has
> to iterate over is not known in advance and grows significantly, and,
> consequently, we end up with nonsensical numbers:
>
> ```
> $ git commit-graph write --reachable
> Expanding reachable commits in commit graph: 138606% (824706/595), done.
> [...]
>
> $ git rev-parse v5.0 | git commit-graph write --stdin-commits
> Expanding reachable commits in commit graph: 81264400% (812644/1), done.
> [...]
> ```
>
> Even worse, because the percentage grows so quickly, the progress code
> outputs much more often than it should (because it ticks every second,
> or every 1%), slowing the whole process down.
> My time for "`git commit-graph write --reachable`" on `linux.git` went from `13.463s` to `12.521s` with this patch, `~7%` savings.
>
> Therefore, don't show progress percentages in the "Expanding reachable
> commits in commit graph" phase.

---

Git 2.24 (Q4 2019) adds another optimization.

See [commit 7371612](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7371612255492f062ee905e6d88c6234c6d4752a) (26 Aug 2019) by [Garima Singh (`singhgarima`)](https://github.com/singhgarima).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit caf150c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/caf150ce7d60e4070292226ec208478b801b8d4b), 07 Oct 2019)</sup>

> `commit-graph`: add `--[no-]progress` to write and verify

> Add `--[no-]progress` to `git commit-graph write` and `verify`.
> The progress feature was introduced in [7b0f229](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b0f2292224cec841de78acc911e4c378ea79faa)
> ("`commit-graph write`: add progress output", 2018-09-17, Git v2.20.0-rc0) but
> the ability to opt-out was overlooked.

---

With Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), "`git merge-base --is-ancestor`" is taught to take advantage of the commit graph.

See [commit 80b8ada](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80b8ada54756e972b01d20b98a388fbbc3a2fe58), [commit d91d6fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d91d6fbf26663ab64c453411c2de6cf4ea754246) (17 Jun 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dc4b3cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc4b3cfb92c82d5516955d8db642ec4e6bc4671b), 25 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`commit-reach`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80b8ada54756e972b01d20b98a388fbbc3a2fe58): use fast logic in `repo_in_merge_base`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Reported-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The `repo_is_descendant_of()` method is aware of the existence of the commit-graph file. It checks for `generation_numbers_enabled()` before deciding on using `can_all_from_reach()` or `repo_in_merge_bases()` depending on the situation. The reason here is that `can_all_from_reach()` uses a depth-first search that is limited by the minimum generation number of the target commits, and that algorithm can be very slow when generation numbers are not present. The alternative uses `paint_down_to_common()` which will walk the entire merge-base boundary, which is typically slower.
>
> This method is used by commands like "`git tag --contains`" and "`git branch --contains`" for very fast results when a commit-graph file exists.
> Unfortunately, it is *not* used in commands like "`git merge-base --is-ancestor`" which is doing an even simpler request.
>
> This issue was [raised recently](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20200607195347.GA8232@szeder.dev/) with respect to a change to how generation numbers are stored, but was also [reported much earlier](https://lore.kernel.org/git/87608bawoa.fsf@evledraar.gmail.com/) before [`commit-reach.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/80b8ada54756e972b01d20b98a388fbbc3a2fe58/commit-reach.c) existed to simplify these reachability queries.
>
> The root cause is that [`builtin/merge-base.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/80b8ada54756e972b01d20b98a388fbbc3a2fe58/builtin/merge-base.c) has a method `handle_is_ancestor()` that calls `in_merge_bases()`, an older version of `repo_in_merge_bases()`.
> It would be better if we have every caller to `in_merge_bases()` use the logic in `can_all_from_reach()` when possible.
>
> This is where things get a little tricky: `repo_is_descendant_of()` calls `repo_in_merge_bases()` in the non-generation numbers enabled case! If we simply update `repo_in_merge_bases()` to call `repo_is_descendant_of()` instead of `repo_in_merge_bases_many()`, then we will get a recursive call loop. Thankfully, this is caught by the test suite in the default mode (i.e. `GIT_TEST_COMMIT_GRAPH=0`).
>
> The trick, then, is to make the non-generation number case for `repo_is_descendant_of()` call `repo_in_merge_bases_many()` directly, skipping the `non-_many` version. This allows us to take advantage of this faster code path, when possible.
>
> The easiest way to measure the performance impact is to test the following command on the Linux kernel repository:
>
> ```
> git merge-base --is-ancestor <A> <B>
>
> | A    | B    | Time Before | Time After |
> |------|------|-------------|------------|
> | v3.0 | v5.7 | 0.459s      | 0.028s     |
> | v4.0 | v5.7 | 0.267s      | 0.021s     |
> | v5.0 | v5.7 | 0.074s      | 0.013s     |
> ```
>
> Note that each of these samples return success. The old code performed the same operation when `<A>` and `<B>` are swapped.
> However, `can_all_from_reach()` will return immediately if the generation numbers show that `<A>` has larger generation number than `<B>`.
> Thus, the time for the swapped case is universally 0.004s in each case.

---

With Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), `is_descendant_of()` is no longer used:

See [commit c1ea625](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1ea625f72110fda87fd225d7dff002befb82d9f) (23 Jun 2020) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0258ed1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0258ed1e08e7973f1d6829db8d33109851067a91), 06 Jul 2020)</sup>

> ### [`commit-reach`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1ea625f72110fda87fd225d7dff002befb82d9f): avoid `is_descendant_of()` shim
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> [d91d6fbf26](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d91d6fbf26663ab64c453411c2de6cf4ea754246) ("`commit-reach`: create `repo_is_descendant_of()`", 2020-06-17, Git v2.28.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc4b3cfb92c82d5516955d8db642ec4e6bc4671b) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f402ea68166bd77f09b176c96005ac7f8886e14b)) adds a repository aware version of `is_descendant_of()` and a backward compatibility shim that is barely used.
>
> Update all callers to directly use the new `repo_is_descendant_of()` function instead; making the codebase simpler and pushing more `the_repository` references higher up the stack.

---

Also, before Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), the code to implement "[`git merge-base --independent`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/48923e83568caa631968b39fd99a75389be0a982/Documentation/git-merge-base.txt#L48)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-base#Documentation/git-merge-base.txt---independent))</sup> was poorly done and was kept from the very beginning of the feature.

See [commit 41f3c99](https://github.com/git/git/commit/41f3c9949fc384f6a122e7d23bc36b7d9bb96ce2), [commit 3677773](https://github.com/git/git/commit/36777733713afeee31e7cf2dbb6d6a3dac186a51), [commit c8d693e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8d693e1e6d3bd883224559cf4c1b07d9d58e0cf), [commit fbc21e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fbc21e3fbba982c50a3c2a273038770a249ed510) (19 Feb 2021), and [commit 0fac156](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0fac15652322e607ef3cb9f59e46ca2b168e933a) (01 Feb 2021) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 48923e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48923e83568caa631968b39fd99a75389be0a982), 25 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`commit-reach`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/36777733713afeee31e7cf2dbb6d6a3dac186a51): use heuristic in `remove_redundant()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Reachability algorithms in [`commit-reach.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/36777733713afeee31e7cf2dbb6d6a3dac186a51/commit-reach.c) frequently benefit from using the first-parent history as a heuristic for satisfying reachability queries.
> The most obvious example was implemented in [4fbcca4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fbcca4effc1c6f8431120f88f5a4bd1c8e38ca3) ("`commit-reach`: make `can_all_from_reach`...
> linear", 2018-07-20, Git v2.20.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b7a91da71d42759dfb83fa3a17be54ad01f0132) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2d3b1c576c85b7f5db1f418907af00ab88e0c303)).
>
> Update the walk in `remove_redundant()` to use this same heuristic.
> Here, we are walking starting at the parents of the input commits.
> Sort those parents and walk from the highest generation to lower.
> Each time, use the heuristic of searching the first parent history before continuing to expand the walk.
>
> The order in which we explore the commits matters, so update `compare_commits_by_gen` to break generation number ties with commit date.
> This has no effect when the commits are in a commit-graph file with corrected commit dates computed, but it will assist when the commits are in the region "above" the commit-graph with "infinite" generation number.
> Note that we cannot shift to use `compare_commits_by_gen_then_commit_date` as the method prototype is different.
> We use `compare_commits_by_gen` for `QSORT()` as opposed to as a priority function.
>
> The important piece is to ensure we short-circuit the walk when we find that there is a single non-redundant commit.
> This happens frequently when looking for merge-bases or comparing several tags with '[`git merge-base --independent`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/36777733713afeee31e7cf2dbb6d6a3dac186a51/Documentation/git-merge-base.txt#L48)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-base#Documentation/git-merge-base.txt---independent))</sup>.
> Use a new count '`count_still_independent`' and if that hits 1 we can stop walking.
>
> To update '`count_still_independent`' properly, we add use of the RESULT flag on the input commits.
> Then we can detect when we reach one of these commits and decrease the count.
> We need to remove the RESULT flag at that moment because we might re-visit that commit when popping the stack.
>
> We use the STALE flag to mark parents that have been added to the new `walk_start` list, but we need to clear that flag before we start walking so those flags don't halt our depth-first-search walk.
>
> On my copy of the Linux kernel repository, the performance of '`git merge-base --independent`' `<all-tags>` goes from 1.1 seconds to 0.11 seconds.

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), the common code to deal with "chunked file format" that is shared by the multi-pack-index and commit-graph files have been factored out, to help codepaths for both filetypes to become more robust.

See [commit c4ff24b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4ff24bbb354377a6a7937744fbbef2898243fc7) (24 Feb 2021) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
See [commit a43a2e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a43a2e6c2af63e5b93444c8ed8ac252927c2f0f3), [commit 5387fef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5387fefadc121cb142e513557997415f2e75188a), [commit 329fac3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/329fac3a366244ceac599ab63cd338bcc6a1dcb4), [commit 6ab3b8b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ab3b8b8b8dc94c8e4caefb1d368cc704e70d38b), [commit 2692c2f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2692c2f6fd1cc9f74e433cb05d5756575682b9ab), [commit 5f0879f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f0879f54b1f5cda348528a49af57a9c3fd620f9), [commit 63a8f0e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63a8f0e9b9d9ce636738094391619c35856f7665), [commit c144241](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1442410d869cd5fb2c0dd79aa1a7c152b99b0f9), [commit 0ccd713](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ccd713cb6c4dafd36bdf85384becbb9b38504ba), [commit 980f525](https://github.com/git/git/commit/980f525c3cee7e272136eeb6e988a66f5f8a0bd8), [commit 7a3ada1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a3ada1192bd251e530a668f63a65b4befa076d0), [commit 31bda9a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/31bda9a237b363574bd8a5bd98f86bdeb6ced1e6), [commit b4d9414](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b4d941420bce15cd48bccabc1faa90477bda2fae), [commit 577dc49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/577dc49696afee67fb507e0bd72be4c8677b83c2), [commit 47410aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47410aa8370fdfc67d379fc808ac2316aef1d2c5), [commit 570df42](https://github.com/git/git/commit/570df42610a971b80046846d7f262007bec23dd6) (18 Feb 2021), and [commit eb90719](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb9071912f5ca370d7e30e88434ffa10c182ed81) (05 Feb 2021) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 660dd97](https://github.com/git/git/commit/660dd97a62da66ffe95df20a9e27a01e39ae473f), 01 Mar 2021)</sup>

> ### [`commit-graph.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c4ff24bbb354377a6a7937744fbbef2898243fc7): display correct number of chunks when writing
>
> <sup>Reported-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> When writing a commit-graph, a progress meter is shown which indicates the number of pieces of data to write (one per commit in each chunk).
>
> In [47410aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47410aa8370fdfc67d379fc808ac2316aef1d2c5) ("`commit-graph`: use chunk-format write API", 2021-02-18, Git v2.32.0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/660dd97a62da66ffe95df20a9e27a01e39ae473f)), the number of chunks became tracked by the new chunk-format API.
> But a stray local variable was left behind from when `write_commit_graph_file()` used to keep track of the same.
>
> Since this was no longer updated after [47410aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47410aa8370fdfc67d379fc808ac2316aef1d2c5), the progress meter appeared broken:
>
> ```
> $ git commit-graph write --reachable
> Expanding reachable commits in commit graph: 837569, done.
> Writing out commit graph in 3 passes: 166% (4187845/2512707), done.
> ```
>
> Drop the local variable and rely instead on the chunk-format API to tell us the correct number of chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.38 (Q3 2022) offers another approach (beside the original commit-graph mentioned in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52505170/6309)).

See [commit 359b01c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/359b01ca8424dcfea9504236365f42b4e0d1aaea) (11 Jul 2022) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 40ab711](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40ab711a9cd2b018bce53264da8d3d65085cfb53), 19 Jul 2022)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/359b01ca8424dcfea9504236365f42b4e0d1aaea): disable `save_commit_buffer` while traversing
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> Various `ref-filter` options like "`--contains`" or "`--merged`" may cause us to traverse large segments of the history graph.
> It's counter-productive to have `save_commit_buffer` turned on, as that will instruct the commit code to cache in-memory the object contents for each commit we traverse.
>
> This increases the amount of heap memory used while providing little or no benefit, since we're not actually planning to display those commits (which is the usual reason that tools like [`git-log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/359b01ca8424dcfea9504236365f42b4e0d1aaea/Documentation/git-log.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> want to keep them around).
> We can easily disable this feature while `ref-filter` is running.
> This lowers peak heap (as measured by massif) for running:
>
> ```
> git tag --contains 1da177e4c3
> ```
>
> in linux.git from ~100MB to ~20MB.
> It also seems to improve runtime by 4-5% (600ms vs 630ms).
>
> A few points to note:
>
> - it should be safe to temporarily disable `save_commit_buffer` like this.
>   The saved buffers are accessed through `get_commit_buffer()`, which treats the saved ones like a cache, and loads on-demand from the object database on a cache miss.
>   So any code that was using this would not be wrong, it might just incur an extra object lookup for some objects.
>   But...
> - I don't think any `ref-filter` related code is using the cache.
>   While it's true that an option like "`--format=%(*contents:subject)`" or
>   "`--sort=*authordate`" will need to look at the commit contents,
>   `ref-filter` doesn't use `get_commit_buffer()` to do so!
>   It always reads
>   the objects directly via `read_object_file()`, though it does avoid
>   re-reading objects if the format can be satisfied without them.
>
> Timing "`git tag --format=%(*authordate)`" shows that we're the same
> before and after, as expected.
>
> - Note that all of this assumes you don't have a commit-graph file.
>   If you do, then the heap usage is even lower, and the runtime is 10x faster.
>   So in that sense this is not urgent, as there's a much better solution.
>   But since it's such an obvious and easy win for fallback cases (including commits which aren't yet in the graph file), there's no reason not to.